# Delete Published Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I created a code wiki.  Worked nicely.
Decided to take a look at published wikis so added one and then found that it overrode the code wiki (wtf?)
Then I discover that I can't go back (double wtf?)

Eventually, after much faffing about I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops#delete-project-wiki

Talk about a PITA, but it worked.  This morning I look at the wiki again and the empty published wiki is back.

However, the above solution no longer works.  Running "az devops wiki list" just shows the single codeWiki.  No mention of the projectWiki and so, I have no repositoryId to call DELETE against.

So, two questions:

1. How do I get back to the codeWiki?
2. Has there been any indication of when MS are going to fix this ridiculous manual delete situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your wikis here:
[image]
You can refer to the document if you want to delete your wiki pages:

Code wiki:[Edit, rename, or delete pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#edit-rename-or-delete-pages)

[image]

Project wiki:[Edit and delete wiki pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#edit-and-delete-wiki-pages)

[image]

Comment: Oh good god, that little expander is really not very obvious tucked away down the bottom there.  Thanks

Comment: Although, your comments about deleting wiki pages don't apply to the project wiki.  You still have to go through the ridiculous REST api dance.